# Copy values between sheets but switching the end result to -/+ depending on the original value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code to copy values between sheets either as a single value from a cell to a cell or a sum of cells.  the difficulty is trying to convert the end result to -/+.  If the value on sheet 1 is positive then show it as a negative on the sheet 2, and if sheet 1 value is negative then show it as positive on sheet 2.  Also, if the sum of values is negative then show it as a positive etc.

So far I have put this together but I'm not having much luck. Please can someone tell me what am doing wrong?

```
If Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E4").Value < 0 Then _
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E4").Copy
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("G4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'the answer        needs to be in +
Else
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E4").Copy
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("G4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'the answer nees to be in -


If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E4") _
, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E6")) < 0 Then

Worksheets("sheet2").Range("G4") =    WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E4") _
, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E6")) 'the answer needs to be in +
Else
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("G4") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E4") _
, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E6")) 'the answer needs to be in -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply subtract the value(s) from 0 to flip positive to negative and vice versa.

```
Sub flipSign()
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ws2.Range("G4") = 0 - .Range("E4").Value
        ws2.Range("G4") = 0 - .Range("E6").Value
        ws2.Range("G4") = 0 - Application.Sum(.Range("E4, E6"))
    End With
End Sub
```

I suppose your sample code was just a test bed and you are planning to change the destination(s) but this should get you started.

Comment: Jeeped, many thanks.  Short & sweet.  Yes, it is a test bed.  The actual file has 40 sheets with several reference cells on each sheet.